# Is there a way to preserve or track vertex correspondence after a series of vertex removals

Tags: python, igraph

In python-igraph, it seems to me that when you delete vertices from a graph, the vertices are renamed to using consecutive vertices from 0 to `n`.

To see what I mean, consider the following program:

```
from igraph import Graph

g=Graph.Full(4) # Vertex set is {0..3}

print g.neighbors(2) # Prints [0,1,3]
g.delete_vertices([1])
print g.neighbors(2) # Prints [0,1], but I'd want [0,3]
```

I could do my own manual bookkeeping, but is this already supported in the library somehow? Basically, I'd like to know after a series of vertex deletions, what the newly renamed vertices correspond to in the original graph (just like in the snippet above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to use the `name` vertex attribute to track the correspondence. Basically, if you assign names to the vertices, you can then use the names later wherever igraph expects a numeric vertex ID:

```
>>> g.vs["name"] = ["V{0}".format(i) for i in range(4)]
>>> g.vs[g.neighbors("V2")]["name"]
['V0', 'V1', 'V3']
>>> g.delete_vertices(["V1"])
>>> g.vs[g.neighbors("V2")]["name"]
['V0', 'V3']
```

The `name` attribute is indexed behind the scenes so looking up a vertex by name should have the same time complexity as a typical Python dict lookup.

For what it's worth, the vertex renumbering is a property of the underlying C library so there's not much that the Python interface can do about it.